# Failed to pip install pandas in win10 64

Tags: python, pandas, pip, installation, python-3.4

I'm trying to install Python34 pandas module on a win64 machine (win10)
Downloaded the pandas-0.20.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

All prerequisites are installed.

Trying to pip install, I get:

pandas-0.20.3-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running `python3 -m pip install pandas` on a command line instead? That should just do the whole thing for you.

Comment: You said you downloaded `cp35`, which is for Python 3.5, not 3.4. But your error message says `cp34`, which would mean Python 3.4. Make sure you downloaded the right one and try again...